# Anchor to specific tr in a table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

I have a scroll-able HTML table and based on the data on the table I want the table to start showing from a particular `<tr>`. The rows above can be shown upon scroll. But when the page loads, I need to position to a particular `<tr>`

I'm able to fetch the `<tr>` that I require to position using the below code. I'm not sure how to set the position.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myTr = $(".slash-price:first").closest('tr');
    });
</script>
```

My Tr is the `<tr>` I want to show first in the table element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should smooth animate the position to the row that you have selected with `closest('tr')`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var myTr = $(".slash-price:first").closest('tr');
        $('html, body').animate({
           scrollTop: $(myTr).offset().top
        }, 2000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That actually worked. But now the tr is positioned at top 0. I want it to be further below the table header. Which part should I change to alter the top pixels?

Comment: Ok so you want the `tr` to not end up right at the top - but say 50px lower?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so I ended up using top - 620

```
var myTr = $(".slash-price:first").closest('tr');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $(myTr).offset().top - 620
        }, 2000);
```